# How to select biggest variable from a list

Tags: sql-server

After storing some results from calculations into different variables i want to select the biggest of them and store the value in a new variable.
I've tried to use the MAX function (see the try under) but I can't find the syntax error.

Example:

```
DECLARE @BNTL FLOAT = (SELECT [numericvalue] FROM [table] WHERE [condition])
DECLARE @BNTT FLOAT = (SELECT [numericvalue] FROM [table] WHERE [condition])
DECLARE @BNTC FLOAT = (SELECT [numericvalue] FROM [table] WHERE [condition])
DECLARE @GNTL FLOAT = (SELECT [numericvalue] FROM [table] WHERE [condition])
DECLARE @GNTT FLOAT = (SELECT [numericvalue] FROM [table] WHERE [condition])
DECLARE @GNTC FLOAT = (SELECT [numericvalue] FROM [table] WHERE [condition])
DECLARE @BTAC FLOAT = (SELECT [numericvalue] FROM [table] WHERE [condition])
DECLARE @BTAT FLOAT = (SELECT [numericvalue] FROM [table] WHERE [condition])
DECLARE @BTAL FLOAT = (SELECT [numericvalue] FROM [table] WHERE [condition])

DECLARE @aBNT FLOAT 
DECLARE @aGNT FLOAT 
DECLARE @aBTA FLOAT 

DECLARE @MaxValue FLOAT
    
SELECT @aBNT = 1.0*((@BNTC/@BNTT)/@BNTL)
SELECT @aGNT = 1.0*((@GNTC/@GNTT)/@GNTL)
SELECT @aBTA = 1.0*((@BTAC/@BTAT)/@BTAL)

SELECT MAX(@MaxValue) FROM (VALUES (@aBNT),(@aGNT),(@aBTA))
```

Comment: Your `VALUES` table construct doesn't have an alias, and neither doesn't the column within it. Also `MAX(@MaxValue)` would also return the value of `@MaxValue`, as the `MAX` of a single value, is always the value itself.

Comment: Though, I must admit, performing 9 `SELECT`s against a single table seems somewhat unperformant; I suspect there is another underlying problem and you may well be able to do the whole operation in a single statement.

Comment: If you're on MSSQL 2022, you max use greatest function. Otherwise, check this answer out. Second answer is the one you need
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/187090/does-sql-server-support-greatest-and-least-if-not-what-is-the-common-workaround